# Setup Excel 2010 sheet that automatically popluates bi weekly dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to set it up where if I fill in a date it will automatically fill in the next column and on down. For example:
A1= `10/06/14`   B1= `10/19/14`

I want A/B 2 to be `10/20/14` and `11/02/14`. I found this code, but it only changes the dates to the 10 and 25. How would I modify it for my use.

"Copy this to A2

```
=DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1), DAY(B1)+1)
```

and copy this into B2;

```
=IF(DAY(B1)=10, DATE(YEAR(B1), MONTH(B1), DAY(25)), DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)+1, DAY(10)))
```

Go ahead and highlight A2 and B2 to drag them down as far as you need. "

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One method to try is:

- Ensure that the cells are formatted to be dates, and in English(US) format (for the dates you described).
- Then add 14 (to advance by the biweekly or fortnightly amount) to the cells in row 1

For example, in cell A1, I put in the date `10/06/14` and in cell A2, I put the formula `=A1+14`, which gave me the date `10/20/14`  and found it gave me the correct value for column B as well, using the formula `=B1+14`.

This method also allows the correct dates to populate subsequent cells when dragged down the columns.